# Carregar imagens usando PHP?

Tags: php, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Tenho uma página que carrega cerca de 90% do conteúdo com base em imagens, o tamanho das imagens varia de 20kb até 150kb dependendo do tamanho da mesma, para melhorar a performance de carregamento da página estou pensando em chamar as imagens através de um script php, que vai identificar se o usuário está usando Chrome ou outro navegador com suporte a WebP, e então carregar a imagem com a extensão mais apropriada para o navegador. Minha dúvida é:

- É uma boa fazer essa chamada através de um script php?

Comment: 90% do conteúdo é imagem, mas o usuário vê todo esse conteúdo por vez? Uma boa saída para poupar recursos tanto do servidor quanto do cliente seria usar a estratégia de lazy loading das imagens.

Comment: Na home tenho um banner que ocupa 90% da resolução do usuário, seguido de uma lista com aproximadamente 30 imagens, quando o usuário der scroll mais 10 listas dessas são criadas, e quando ele chegar no final outras 10 serão criadas novamente.

Comment: Quando o usuário dá scroll ele carrega 300 imagens?

Comment: Atualmente são carregadas aproximadamente 100 imagens iniciais e a cada lista temos as mesmas imagens organizadas de forma diferente, mas sim num futuro próximo vai ser algo como isso 300/400 imagens ao total

Comment: Dependendo de como está seu layout o lazy loading ainda sim seria uma boa. Veja http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/infinite.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na minha opinião, não é uma boa usar o PHP para carregar imagens.

Se fizer assim, você estará fazendo com que o PHP tenha que processar todo o conteúdo de uma imagem para depois enviar uma resposta ao navegador.

Isso pode custar caro para o servidor em termos de processamento, já que o PHP precisa utilizar a memória para poder renderizar essa imagem.

Sem contar que o browser tem um mecanismo específico para caches de imagem. Talvez fazendo pelo PHP, você não possa usufruir dessa funcionalidade, já que na verdade é um script PHP que será processado, e não uma imagem.

A solução que costumo utilizar para casos onde eu preciso usar o PHP para processar imagens é: Processo a imagem uma vez, dando a ela o formato desejado, e salvo-a. Costumo convertê-las todas para o mesmo formato.

Creio que se você deseja melhorar a performance de suas imagens, você possa investir um tempo na criação de um sistema de thumbs. Utilizando imagens redimensionadas ou com tratamento adequado, você pode atingir uma performance desejada.  Mas não creio que carregar sempre com um script PHP seja adequado. Agora, se fizer isso uma vez, criando uma imagem otimiza estática, acho que seria uma boa solução.

Comment: mas processando através do php eu posso usar header para criar o cache dos arquivos, se você acessar a netflix no chrome e no firefox verá que a extensão das imagens são diferente nos dois navegadores, como eles fazem isso?

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma, você está usando o PHP para processar as imagens. Convenhamos que você precisa de dois passos: O PHP processando a imagem e a resposta sendo enviada para o navegador. No caso da imagem estática, o navegador só precisa ler a imagem e pronto.

Comment: Então é uma má ideia também usar PHP para fazer stream de vídeo? Tive essa ideia a partir desse recurso

Comment: Concordo que vai usar memória do servidor à toa, mas quem vai renderizar a imagem é o browser. O PHP só está servindo os bytes, mesmo quando você estiver acessando uma página com extensão `.php` quem vai decidir o que fazer com o que foi servido é o navegador.

Comment: @Thomas o problema é que se ele não souber fazer direito, a resposta vinda do apache viria como `200`, se não me engano imagem vem como `304`. Sem contar outros headers específicos que o povo sempre esquece de botar quando faz esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Na verdade, eu não tenho muita experiência com tratamento de imagens, mas posso garantir que usar um arquivo estático seria melhor que processar tudo antes por um script. A não ser que ele precise fazer algo especificamente dentro desse script, aí talvez o compense por outro lado.

Comment: Aqui as imagens vem como 200

Comment: @LeoLetto todas as vezes que você recarrega a página?

Comment: Sim, se o problema for consumo de memória não há problema pois as mesmas são carregadas a partir de um server dedicado, razoavelmente bom

Comment: Você é quem sabe, jovem. Só que não posso deixar de citar que acho que esse não seria o caminho. Eu preferia ter a imagem replicada 2 vezes no meu servidor e fazer essa exibição de acordo com o browser através de uma decisão do Javascript, do que ter que processar toda hora através de um script PHP.

Comment: Mas esse é o ponto, as imagens vão ser duplicadas em jpg e webp, só estou pensando em usar o script php para detectar de qual browser foi feita a chamada, e não para criar a imagem na hora

Comment: O problema de vir como `200` todas as vezes é que as imagens estão sendo baixadas todas as vezes que são acessadas. O ideal seria que elas ficassem em cache, e quando acessadas uma segunda vez, não precisasse baixar novamente.

Comment: Mas elas estão vindo como 200 e estão sendo carregadas a partir do disco local

Comment: @Thomas então, eu deixaria um cache estático no servidor, mas aí é bem complicado. Ele perguntou "se era uma boa ou não", por isso não vou exemplificar, senão seria muito ampla a pergunta.

Comment: @LeoLetto bem, a resposta já dei: Não é uma boa. A não ser que você precise fazer coisas bem específicas com cada imagem carregada (como controle de quantidade de visualizações por exemplo). Agora, se a sua dúvida é sobre "como fazer", aí teria que formular outra pergunta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendo, bom vou usar jquery para detectar o userAgent e carregar a extensão de acordo com o user obtido, assumindo o que foi visto aqui, é uma uma má ideia também usar PHP para fazer vídeo stream, ou ele apenas vai exigir um pouco mais de processamento, mas vai dar um melhor desempenho para o cliente?

Comment: @LeoLetto você está fazendo muitas perguntas num assunto que foi específico para "é bom ou não usar PHP para carregar imagens". Eu sugiro você fazer outra (ou outras) perguntas. O espaço dos comentários é pequeno pra explicar essas coisas.